# Hashmap with Linked List to find word count

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap, cpu-word

I have been working on this little project for quite some time and I can't figure out why I'm not getting the results that are expected. I am a beginner to C programming so my understanding with pointers and memory allocation/deallocation is novice. Anyways, I have constructed this segment of code by originally building a hash function, then adding a count to it. However, when I test it, sometimes the count works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm not sure whether it's the fault of the hash function, or the fault of the way I set up my count. The text file is read one line at a time and is a string consisting of a hexadecimal.

```
    struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
    int count;  /* Implement count here for word frequencies */
};

#define H_SIZE 1024
struct node *hashtable[H_SIZE]; /* Declaration of hash table */

void h_lookup(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct node *tmp;

    for(i = 0; i < H_SIZE; i++) {

        for(tmp = hashtable[i]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
            if(tmp->data != 0) {
                        printf("Index: %d\nData: %s\nCount: %d\n\n", i,
                                 tmp->data, tmp->count);
            }
        }

    }
}


/* self explanatory */

void h_add(char *data)
{
    unsigned int i = h_assign(data);
    struct node *tmp;
    char *strdup(const char *s);


    /* Checks to see if data exists, consider inserting COUNT here */

    for(tmp = hashtable[i]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {

        if(tmp->data != 0) { /*  root node */
            int count = tmp->count;
            if(!strcmp(data, tmp->data))

                count= count+1;
            tmp->count = count;
                    return;
        }
    }

    for(tmp = hashtable[i]; tmp->next != NULL; tmp = tmp->next);

    if(tmp->next == NULL) { 
             tmp->next = h_alloc();
             tmp = tmp->next;
             tmp->data = strdup(data);
             tmp->next = NULL;
             tmp->count = 1;
    } else
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

/* Hash function, takes value (string) and converts into an index into the array of linked lists) */

unsigned int h_assign(char *string)
{
    unsigned int num = 0;

    while(*string++ != '\0')
            num += *string;

    return num % H_SIZE;
}

/* h_initialize(void) initializes the array of linked lists. Allocates one node for each list by calling h_alloc which creates a new node and sets node.next to null */

void h_initialize(void)
{   int i;
    for(i = 0; i <H_SIZE; i++) {
          hashtable[i] = h_alloc();
    }

}

/* h_alloc(void) is a method which creates a new node and sets it's pointer to null */

struct node *h_alloc(void)
{
    struct node *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));

    if (tmp != NULL){
        tmp->next = NULL;
        return tmp;
    }

    else{
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* Clean up hashtable and free up memory */

void h_free(void)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    struct node *fwd;
    int x;

    for(x = 0; x < H_SIZE; x++) {

          tmp = hashtable[x];
          while(tmp != NULL) {
                  fwd = tmp->next;

              free(tmp->data);
              free(tmp);

              tmp = fwd;

          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the count is not being incremented when it does not work. It is possible that strdup is not able to allocate memory for the new string and is returning NULL. You should check the return value to and exit gracefully if it fails.

Comment: Are you sure? Because strdup allocates memory with malloc and free's memory with free(); I have checked the returns and that's the result I came to.

The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s. Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

Comment: I would check the pointer for NULL right after the call to strdup, but that may not be the issue here. Can you give more information on how the count fails? Are you getting to the printf statement in h_lookup?